# Angular 2 Dynamic Components can't use input from parent, but I see it

Tags: typescript, angular

I am instantiating component via dynamic component loader, all well there.

PARENT:

```
dcl.loadAsRoot(detailComponent, '#detail', injector).then(componentRef => {
    componentRef.instance.item = "milano"
})
```

CHILD:

```
console.log(this) // I see here: item: "milano"
console.log(this.item)  // I get: "undefined"
console.log(_.keys(this)) // I see all keys, but not the "item" key
```

How can I access "this.item" in child which is loaded dynamically?

PS. I also tried by adding @Input item at the top, and it does not work either.

Comment: Don't use loadAsRoot, as simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6370#issuecomment-193896657

> when using loadAsRoot you need to trigger change detection and manually wire up Inputs, Outputs, Injector, and the component dispose function

```
function onYourComponentDispose() {
}
let el = this.elementRef
let reuseInjectorOrCreateNewOne = this.injector;
this.componentLoader.loadAsRoot(YourComponent, this.elementRef, reuseInjectorOrCreateNewOne, onYourComponentDispose)
.then((compRef: ComponentRef) => {
  // manually include Inputs
  compRef.instance['myInputValue'] = {res: 'randomDataFromParent'};
  // manually include Outputs
  compRef.instance['myOutputValue'].subscribe(this.parentObserver)
  // trigger change detection
  cmpRef.location.internalElement.parentView.changeDetector.ref.detectChanges()
  // always return in a promise
  return compRef
});
```

See also
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7453#issuecomment-193138587
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6071#issuecomment-202765309

Comment: How do we use `@output` in `viewContainerRef` as `Dynamic Component Loader` is deprecated?